# How to add custom theme to element-ui in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I want to add custom theme to element-ui.

I have installed element-ui, babel-plugin-component.

Nuxt src directory

```
module.exports = {
  srcDir: 'client/',
...
```

Add nuxt plugin

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {
  Button,
...
} from 'element-ui';

import lang   from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/ru-RU';
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale';

locale.use(lang);

Vue.use(Button);
...
```

Add plugin to nuxt config

```
{ src: '@/plugins/element-ui.js' },
```

.babelrc file

```
{
  "babelrc": true,
  "cacheDirectory": false,
  "presets": ["@nuxt/babel-preset-app"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "component",
      {
        "libraryName": "element-ui",
        "styleLibraryName": "~client/assets/styles/element-ui/theme"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Theme don't load.

How to fix it?

Comment: do you have update/answer for this?